# Set value on model when checkbox changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have a page which contains usnernames and checkboxes for every user.
it looks like a matrix.

Now when changing one of the checkboxes, I want to change a value on the user, so I know which user is changed. This way I can check which users I need to update in the database.

My page-code looks as follows:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeList.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeList[i].Id"/>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">@Model.EmployeeList[i].Name @Model.EmployeeList[i].Surname</th>
<th scope="row">@Model.EmployeeList[i].Location</th>
@for (var j = 0; j < Model.EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList.Count; j++)
{
<td>

    @*<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check</label>
    </div>*@
        <label class="label">
            <input asp-for="EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList[j].IsSelected" type="checkbox" class="label__checkbox"/>
            <span class="label__text">
                <span class="label__check">
                    <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
                </span>
            </span>
        </label>

    @*<input asp-for="EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList[j].IsSelected" type="checkbox" />*@
    @*If this is not included, prefix becomes null*@
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList[j].Prefix)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged)
</td>
}
</tr>
}
```

When I click the checkbox I would like to set the value of Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged to true.

Comment: An Id should be unique for an element. For that reason you will get different Ids for hiddens. I don't remember how is composed the MVC Id for repeated elements but that's not a problem: you shall obtain the Id with the HTML helper @Html.Id(Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged)
So, you can bind the Hidden Id to a checkbox attribute in this way:
 <input asp-for=" .. ... " data-changedHidden="@Html.Id(Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged)".
Then,you can bind the onchange event in Javascript, check the bind "data-changedHidden" of the changed checkbox, get the element by id and refresh his val

Comment: @Sycraw : I don't really understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: MVC will generate an ID for "isChanged" hiddens, because there will be more hiddens it should give them a non-fixed id (i.e.: IsChanged_1,IsChanged_2...)
Foreach row, to get the id of specific Hidden you could use @Html.Id(Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged): it should print the Id of the hidden inside that row. Then, you can put it in a custom checkbox attribute to reach something like:
<input type="checkbox" data-changedHidden="IsChanged-3" class="label__checkbox"... />
Then you can use javascript for subscribe the onchanged checkbox event, get his data-changedhidden attribute (continue...)

Comment: ... and because it is the id of the hidden that is rendered in the row, you can use it to reach the specific hidden and update his value.
For semplicty's sake, an example with jQuery :

 <input type="checkbox" data-changedHidden="IsChanged-3" class="label__checkbox"... />
.....

$(
function(){
    $(".label__checkbox").on("change",function(){
        var t=$(this);
        var hdnIsChangedId=t.data("changedHidden");
        var hidden=$("#"+hdnIsChangedId);
        hidden.val("changed!!");
    });
}
);
Get the sample code and format it to get it readable and understandable

Comment: @Sycraw I keep getting an "undefined" on "var hdnIsChangedId = t.data("changedHidden");"

Comment: Have you seen if the checkbox has the data-changedHidden attribute in the rendered HTML? If not try to use @Html.IdFor(m=>Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged) instead of @Html.Id

Comment: I found the problem, I made a typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194056/discussion-between-sycraw-and-bart-schelkens).

Comment: Does it solve the problem? It should be useful to know in order to move key comments to a unique response
even for other users

Comment: I made a typo in the script. I had "changedHidden" insteadof "changedhidden". Correcting this, solved my problem.

Comment: Glad that it solved your trouble, if you can mark the answer as solution that would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, you should know that an Id should be unique for any element. For that reason you will get different Ids for hiddens. I don't remember how is composed the MVC Id for repeated elements but that's not a problem: you shall obtain the Id with the HTML helper @Html.Id(Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged) So, you can bind the Hidden Id to a checkbox attribute in this way:

`<input asp-for=" .. ... " data-changedHidden="@Html.Id(Model.EmployeeList[i].IsChanged)"`

Then,you can bind the onchange event in Javascript, check the bind "data-changedHidden" of the changed checkbox, get the element by id and refresh his val. For example, foreach row you'll get something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-changedHidden="IsChanged-3" class="label__checkbox"... />
```

Then you can use javascript for subscribe the onchanged checkbox event, get his data-changedhidden attribute and because it is the id of the hidden that is rendered in the row, you can use it to reach the specific hidden and update his value. For semplicty's sake, an example with jQuery:

```
$( function(){ 
    $(".label__checkbox").on("change",
        function(){ 
            var t=$(this); 
            var hdnIsChangedId=t.data("changedHidden"); 
            var hidden=$("#"+hdnIsChangedId); 
            hidden.val("changed!!"); 
        }); 
    } );
  );
```